# Git (SourceTree): report file changes without duplicates in date interval

Tags: git, publishing

I'm looking for a very useful feature that could make my day, I searched but found nothing.
I am working on a very big project under GIT ([SourceTree](http://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview)), I made lot of changes to different source files put in different locations. Now I want to publish all my work, but only mine, not all files.

Since I don't trust in automated scripts, I want a list of all files that has changed from last publication, so I can upload them manually.

From SourceTree's GUI, I can search for all my commits from date to date and see all files changes for each commit, but this is not so useful, since the same file has changed more than once, and in this way I should take note of which file I have already uploaded.

Is there a way to make a single full report of all filenames+paths that has changed in a time interval? In this way from the last commit (take origin/master) I'll be able to accomplish my task.

Thank you,

Linuxatico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found that in my actual version of SourceTree (1.6.4.1) if you select with mouse and shift the starting commit and the final commit, it shows exactly what I was looking for: just one occurrence of modified files